# Is it possible to derive the moment generating function?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $M_X(t)=e^t M_X(-t)$. Find $E(X)$ and $E\left(X^2\right)$.

I know the general procedure that to find the expected value, the first order derivative needs to be taken and then t must be set to 0.

$M_X(t)^{\prime}=e^t M_X(-t)-e^t M_X^{\prime}(-t)$

The solution is $E[X] = \frac{1}{2}$, but I don't see how I can evaluate this question without an expression for the MGF or a distribution for the random variable.

Question: Is there sufficent information to answer this question?

Question 2:

\begin{aligned}
&M_x^{(2)}(t)=e^t\left(M_x^{(2)}(-t)-2 M_x^{(1}(-t)+M x(-t)\right) \\
&M_x^{(2)}(0)=M_x^{(2)}(0)-2 M_x^{(1)}(-t)+M x(0)
\end{aligned}

If I differentiate two times, It seems like there is no expression for the second derivative. Does this mean that $E[X]$ is undefined?

Comment: Since $M_X(t) = E(e^{tX}),$ do we know what $M_X(0)$ is? If so, what happens when we plug $t = 0$ into your formula for $M_X'(t)$?

Comment: This is equivalent to $Y:=X-\frac12$ having a symmetric distribution for which the MGF exists, but all we can determine from that about the second-order moments is $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]+\frac14$.

Comment: Do you argree with the derivation of @geetha290krm?

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis says that $X$ and $_X$ have the same MGF. So they have the same distribution. In particular, $E=E(1-X)$ which gives $EX=\frac  1 2$.

There is not enough information to find the second moment, as you have suspected. Here are two examples where the hyptohesis is satisfied but there are different values for $EX^{2}$:

Ex. 1) $X$ Bernoulli. In this case $EX^{2}=\frac   12$.

Ex. 2) $X \sim U(0,1)$. Here $EX^{2}=\frac  1 3$.

Comment: Thank you! Differentiating two times, it seems like there is no expression for the second derivative. How would you deal with this?

Comment: I follow your derivation in the case that the argument of the MGF is $t$ and not $-t$, but when taking the second derivative with $-t$ as argument, I apply the chainrule. As a result, on both sides of the equation I end up with an equally large positive  term for the second derivative. Question: Why is the argument in your derivation non-negative?

Comment: @Tim You are right. I have completely revised my answer. The hypothesis is equivalent to $X $ and $1-X $ having the same distribution.